# Why is the result of the function not reused?

Tags: haskell

When I try to code a shortest path algorithm, I run across a strange thing. After `floydWarshall` function generates adjecency matrix in array form, `main` function tries to query the array multiple times (in `replicateM_` loop).

What I found is that my code is terribly slow. So I put `traceShow "doing"` at the top of `floydWarshall` and re-run to find that each `res ! (start,end)` calls `floydWarshall` repeatedly.

Why does the array re-generates each time?

Full source with sample input:  https://gist.github.com/cwyang/27ab81bee731e6d01bb3a7483fdb748e

```
floydWarshall :: AdjMatrix (Maybe Int) -> AdjMatrix (Maybe Int)
floydWarshall am = traceShow "doing" $ runST $ do
  arr <- thaw am :: ST s (STArray s (Vertex,Vertex) (Maybe Int))
  sequence_ [ go arr k i j | k <- r, i <- r, j <- r]
  freeze arr
  where ((minb,_), (maxb,_)) = bounds am
        r = [minb..maxb]
        go :: STArray s (Vertex,Vertex) (Maybe Int)
           -> Vertex -> Vertex -> Vertex -> ST s ()
        go arr k i j = do
          ij <- readArray arr (i,j)
          ik <- readArray arr (i,k)
          kj <- readArray arr (k,j)
          case (ik, kj) of
            (Nothing, _) -> return ()
            (_, Nothing) -> return ()
            (Just a, Just b) -> case ij of
              Nothing  -> do
                writeArray arr (i,j) $ Just (a+b)
              (Just c) -> when (c > a+b) $ do
                writeArray arr (i,j) $ Just (a+b)
readInt :: B.ByteString -> Int
readInt = fst . fromJust . B.readInt

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [n,m] <- rl
  edges <- replicateM m $ do
    [from,to,weight] <- rl
    return (from,to,weight)
  [q] <- rl
  let am = buildAdjMatrix (1,n) edges
      res= floydWarshall am
  replicateM_ q $ do
    [start,end] <- rl
    putStrLn . show $ maybe (-1) id (res ! (start,end))
  where rl = map readInt . B.words <$> B.getLine
```

Sample run:

```
$ graph < floyd3.txt hs
"doing"     <-- floydWarshall keeps calling
1395
"doing"
975
"doing"
1593
"doing"
1023
"doing"
1521
...
```

Comment: Any chance you have the full code somewhere online? Optimally, you would want to look at the core output to see what is happening, but that's only possible for something that compiles. Also, what flags are you using when you compile?

Comment: Floyd-Warshall is classical dynamic programming algorithm. You can find better approach to solve such problems using _Haskell_ in this post: http://jelv.is/blog/Lazy-Dynamic-Programming/

Comment: i've uploaded full code and sample input: https://gist.github.com/cwyang/27ab81bee731e6d01bb3a7483fdb748e

Comment: compiled with: stack ghc -- -O2  graph.hs

Comment: @Shersh I've read the article. Since flyod-warshall repeatedly modifies its own elements, I could not find way to code in lazy DP sytle, *sigh*

Comment: @cwyang We're missing something here. I'm on GHC 8.0 and your test file linked results in only one `"doing"`, not three, when I run it with the same options (actually, the same result comes from `-O0`, `-O1`, and `-O2`). What version of GHC are you on?

Comment: Oh, I ran on ghc version 7.10.3. I don't want to believe it's version issue though... (same result on -O0,1,2 -- "doing" thrice)

Comment: @alec I tested on ghc 8.0 (base library 4.9.0) and that was fine. When I change `replicateM_` to `forM_`, it runs well on ghc 7.10.x. it might be bug of `replicateM_` in ghc 7.10.x (base library 4.8.2)

Answer (score 4):

Frustratingly, this seems to be caused by the GHC issue ["Costly let binding gets duplicated in IO action value"](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11271).

Using `forM_` rather than `replicateM_` or using `BangPatterns` solves this issue.

Comment: @Shersh's comment above seems quite good: " You can find better approach to solve such problems using Haskell in this post: jelv.is/blog/Lazy-Dynamic-Programming" Generally, you should do as little as possible while in the IO monad... you'll need to change your thinking a bit when programming Haskell, but with time you'll enjoy it more and more :)

Comment: Oh, wow, that is a nasty gotcha. It's one that I, at least, didn't know about, and I've been using Haskell as my go-to language for new projects for almost a decade now, including several years hacking Haskell projects professionally. Perhaps that is some small evidence that this problem doesn't bite very often.

Comment: @mb21 While I agree with the spirit of your comment, the OP is _not_ doing his work inside the `IO` monad, but inside the `ST` monad (the bug is actually not even in the algorithm but in the code that calls it). Also, as this particular algorithm requires a lot of updates `ST` seems like a pretty good choice.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner, [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1168) are more examples.